# Broadcasting a message to a network reliably

Tags: networking

I wrote some software on the Arduino (it's an embedded platform) that broadcasts UDP messages to `255.255.255.255` in port `8888`. This hardware connects to the local network via wifi to a router that provides it with an IP address via DHCP.

In my computer (connected to the same network via wifi) I created a MAX/MSP sketch that listens to UDP messages in the `8888` port and I can receive all the messages being sent from the Arduino without a problem.

What I now need to do is have this system work on a network that I don't control. I just need to be able to plug both devices to the net and be able to have one send messages to the other as in the controlled environment. The aim is to be able to make this setup portable with minimal setup (think interactive art installation). **Is sending messages to `255.255.255.255` a reliable way of broadcasting messages?**

Things you can assume when answering this question:

1. Packets will be relatively short (less than 150 bytes) and will be broadcast once per second or maybe less.
2. The networks will be public wifi networks like a coffee store, a regular house AirPort Express, maybe even those provided for free by a telephone company, or airport ones.
3. I can't configure a specific IP to send a message from the embedded system since I can't compile code and upload to it while on the go. The embedded systems needs a way to be able to send messages no matter what it's linked to.

EDIT: By "reliable" I don't mean that every single packet has to reach the destination every single time. Even 50% packet loss is acceptable in this application. What I want to know is if the above mentioned IP address would work in all networking setups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't always work, and particularily in some public wifi networks which explicitely disable one wifi device talking to other wifi device (for security reasons)

In some of the problematic cases, you'll probably have more luck with having a server somewhere on the internet, and having both your devices talking to it to exchange data.

Note also that connecting to network sometimes may be more complicated (for machine) than just "here is ESSID and  WPA password". I'm just near one in fact: it is captive portal, requiring you to enter your phone number, then it sends you SMS with code, and you must confirm that code on webpage - then that code is linked to that Wifi MAC and no other. So your device would have to have human access (display and keyboard) at least for setup to work in "almost all" scenarios.

You could try with your idea with local broadcast, and then have software fallback to internet access above if it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

By definition, UDP is connectionless, therefore, reliability is only possible if you do handshaking or error checking outside the protocol.

My first instinct is that you should not be broadcasting on 255.255.255.255, that the smaller the broadcast domain, the better results you will have.

Beyond that, this question sets off all of the information security alarms in my head.  My second thought, above, requires you to have at least knowledge of the network to which you're attaching.  And your explicit mention of not having that knowledge puts this in the realm of war driving or MITM.

*edit* - For an art exhibit, does it really need to be reliable?  It seems like a little more randomness would be better.

Comment: This project generates music notes from sensors connected to the Arduino. It also generates a real-time visualization with MAX/MSP via the OSC protocol. It will be displayed anywhere they will allow me to take it as a "cool" thing to watch and listen to. And like I said in the question, it is an art exhibit. I'm sorry it makes you think of war or any other kind of attack (and I think you should not assume negative things about questions right off the bat!). Having said that, by reliable I mean that packets can get from one place to the other. If there is some packet loss, that's ok.

Comment: Also, by "not knowing the network" I meant the coffee shop guy saying "just set it up over there, here's the wifi password". That's it.